# nest.js swagger cannot read generic types define in abstract class controller

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I am trying to use an abstract controller with swagger but nest.js cannot see the generic type `T`. I can't explicitly set the type in decorators because generic types are not available to decorators. So I am stuck. Am I asking something that is not possible in TypeScript?

[image]

Abstract controller

```js
export abstract class AbstractController<T> {
  abstract service: BasicCrud<T>;

  @Get(':id')
  @ApiOkResponse({
    description: 'Successfully returned a matching record',
  })
  @ApiBadRequestResponse({ description: 'Bad request.'})
  async get(@Param('id') id: number): Promise<T> {
    const result = await this.service.get(id);

    if (!result) {
      throw new NotFoundException();
    }

    return result;
  }

  @Get()
  @ApiOkResponse({
    description: 'Successfully returned all matching record',
  })
  async getAll(): Promise<T[]> {
    return await this.service.all();
  }

  @Delete(':id')
  @ApiOkResponse({
    description: 'Successfully deleted a matching record',
  })
  async delete(@Param('id') id: number): Promise<T> {
    const result = await this.service.delete(id);

    if (!result) {
      throw new BadRequestException(`Delete with id ${id} failed`);
    }

    return result;
  }

  @Post()
  @ApiCreatedResponse({ description: 'Successfully saved a new record' })
  async save(@Body() question: T): Promise<T> {
    const result = await this.service.save(question);

    if (!result) {
      throw new BadRequestException('Save failed');
    }

    return result;
  }

  @Put(':id')
  @ApiOkResponse({
    description: 'Successfully updated matching record',
  })
  async update(@Param('id') id: number, @Body() question: T): Promise<T> {
    const result = await this.service.update(id, question);

    if (!result) {
      throw new BadRequestException(`Update with id ${id} failed`);
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

Controller

```js
@ApiTags('user')
@Controller('user')
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
@ApiBearerAuth()
export default class UserController extends AbstractController<User> {
  constructor(private readonly usersService: UsersService) {
    super();
  }

  service: IBasicCrud<User> = this.usersService;
}
```

[Repository](https://github.com/amir734jj/nestjs-template/tree/61fc29230c214abf4050a35cd2ab033984f1b1da)